# Regex PHP contains specific word

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I want to retrieve the first link of my wordpress post in a post custom field. I find out that someone was in the same need as me, and he got a very good answer :

```
function my_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all( '/href\s*=\s*[\"\']([^\"\']+)/', $post->post_content, $matches );

    $first_link = false;
    if ( ! empty( $matches[1][0] ) )
        $first_link = $matches[1][0];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link', esc_url_raw( $first_link ) );
}
```

My issue is, I would like the preg_match_all to have one more condition, **I would like to only retrieve the first link who contain the specific string : *bouture.com***, I think this is possible because their is already a "string condition" with the **href** but I don't know how do it.

Here are some example of links I would like to be retrieved by the REGEX expression :

https://www.bouture.com

https://www.bouture.com/example

https://www.bouture.com/category/post-title/

If you have any ideas that would be awesome !

Thanks !

Comment: you can either use positive lookahead: `/href\s*=\s*[\"\'](?=[^\"\']*bouture.com)([^\"\']+)/`, or iterate through `$matches` and look if anything matches. I would recommend second for you.

Comment: `href\s*=\s*[\"\'](https:\/\/www.bouture.com\/[^\"\']+)` should probably already do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your proposition and it works great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just inspect $matches[1]

```
foreach($matches[1] ?? [] as $url){
    if(stripos($url, 'bouture.com') !== false){
        $first_link = $url;
        break;
    }
}
```